# Why does sample function gives me an error

Tags: r

I am doing a simple sampling using the following code in R.

```
  x=1:1000
  sample1=sample(x, size=30,replace = F)
```

It used to work before but it is not working. I get this error message:

> Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : invalid 'replace' argument

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you sure `length(x) > size`?

Comment: Your code works just fine. Have you perhaps defined a variable `F` somewhere? It's better to be verbose and write `FALSE` instead of the `F` shortcut that can be redefined.

Comment: Did you by any chance define a variable called `F`?

Answer (score 3):

**Do not use `F` and `T` as boolean values in R!** Always use full names `FALSE` and `TRUE`. The variables `F` and `T` can be re-assigned *any* value.

Restart R (if it displays `[Previously saved workspace restored]`, also run `rm(list=ls())`) and try the following:

```
1 == 1
is.logical(c(TRUE, FALSE))
is.logical(c(T, F))

v <- 1:5
v <= 3
(v <= 3) == T
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

F <- 'a'
T <- FALSE

v <- 1:5
v <= 3
(v <= 3) == T
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

I've included the important output.